# Using named parametes multiple times vs. returned datatypes in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Sorry for the long text. The actual question is at the end of this text.

I just switched from `mysqli` to `PDO`.

Using `mysqli` I got data from my database like this:

```
$db = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$dbName);
$db->query('SET NAMES utf8');

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT field FROM table WHERE other_field = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', 1);   // could also be something else
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($field);
$stmt->fetch();   // maybe in a loop
...
```

At the end `$field` contains the value of the field in the database (of one row). But it also has the datatype of this field. So if `field` is declared as `TINYINT`, `$field` contains an integers, if it is declared as a string, it contains a string, and if the value in the database is `NULL`, `$field` is set to `null`.

After switching to `PDO` my code looks like this:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=my_db;charset=UTF8',$user,$pass);

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT field FROM table WHERE other_field = ?');
$stmt->execute([1]);
$stmt->bindColumn(1,$field,PDO::PARAM_INT);   // maybe an other datatype
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);   // maybe in a loop
```

This way I can define which datatype it has to return.

But now the strange things start to happen.

If the field in the database contains `NULL`, it is changed to `0` (integer), if I use `PDO::PARAM_INT`, or to `false`, if I use `PDO::PARAM_BOOL`. So I cannot see if the actual value is `null` or `false`. This seems to happen to all the ways of fetching data.
After some research I found that this can be fixed by turning emulated prepared statements off. So now I'm connecting to my database like this:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=my_db;charset=UTF8',$user, $pass,
               [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false]);
```

Now the returned data types work just fine.

But turning off the emulated prepared statements also removes the possibility to use named parameters multiple times.

E.g.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table 
                      WHERE date_val BETWEEN :date AND :date + INTERVAL 6 DAY')
$stmt->execute(['date' => '2015-06-15']);
```

This works fine, if emulated prepared statements is on, but it results in error `HY093` (Invalid parameter number), if it is turned off.

So my question is:
Is there a `PDO` setting that allow to have both, the correct returned datatypes (including `null`s) and using named parameters multiple times, or do I have to give up one?

Notice: I know that I can write a function to fix the named parameters, if they are used multiple times, or use an other workaround, but I'm looking for a *setting* of PDO or maybe a parameter handed to a PDO function. If there is no such setting, I will give up the named parameters and just stay with the `?`-parameters I already used with `mysqli`.

Comment: whats wrong with naming your parameter differently, `:date1`,`:date2`,`:date3`...

Comment: @meda They would contain the same value, so I want to use one parameter multiple times. If I name them all different, I can also use unnamed parameters. The main thing is, that it is possible, but not if I use real prepared statements. If I emulate them it works, but the returned values get screwed up (in some cases) so I'm looking for a way to get both to work together.

Comment: Right so you would store it to a variable `$date` then `[':date1' => $date, ':date2' => $date]` . if thats not a option for you I would love to know why?

Comment: @meda In my eyes this is a workaround. Actually I use unnamed parameters until I find a *solution* to this misbehavior of `PDO`. There are also other workarounds, like a function that do the renaming for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much more research, I didn't found a solution, but a bug report ([#69257](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69257)).

According to this report, it is a bug, that one can *only* use named parameters multiple times *with emulated* prepared statements.

I now reported the behavior of `bindColumn` to the PHP bug tracker ([#69856](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69856)).

Hopefully both will be fixed sometimes.